# Forever not working with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, forever

I've installed forever using

```
npm install forever -g
```

I've set config in modeljs to safe

```
 migrate: 'safe'
```

Still when I run

```
forever -w start app.js
```

I get this

> warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
>   warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
>   info:    Forever processing file: app.js

I dont want to stop and start my app using sails lift everytime I'm making a change. I'm using sails version of 0.11.

Comment: These are just warnings, and you can safely ignore them. However it is odd that you are getting them, I would try setting it like this.    forever start --minUptime 1000 --spinSleepTime 1000 app.js   It appears it should still be running even with those warnings you have, are you sure it isn't?  Another thing to try is node app.js --prod --port 80 and see if you get any errors running it that way, because forever will run it with node.

Comment: Tried your solution with the minUptime and spinSleepTime, it removed the warnings but no luck with restarting the app on change. So in the end installed sails-hook-autoreload which did the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used [sails-hook-autoreload](https://github.com/sgress454/sails-hook-autoreload) in the end which did the same job with ease.